# JavaFX Scene Builder lacks most of the options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm using `Scene Builder` via `IntellijIDEA`. Suddenly most of the options from the right sidebar **disappeared**. In all tabs!

[image]

Problem occured when I pulled project to another machine. On the previous notebook I used to work with `Gluon Scene Builder` and here the last `Oracle's Scene Builder` was installed. I've changed it to Gluon's version, but it didn't solve the problem. Is it a `bug` or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder <del>is not the same as</del> *uses* Gluon's Scene Builder <del>The former is a version embedded in the IDE, introduced with IntelliJ IDEA 14, [two years ago](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/javaFX/FxBuilderEmbedder)</del>, but without several features (like possibility of adding custom controls), menus or recent improvements<del>, while the latter is the complete and recently [updated](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) version 8.1.1, that allows you using the latest features available.</del>

If you check IntelliJ [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html), they also recommend using the stand-alone version (though they still point to the old 2.0 Oracle's version), they don't refer to the one they embed.

In case you find any issue using Gluon's Scene Builder, you can report it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open).

**Note:** I've edited the answer to clarify that IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder *does use* Gluon's Scene Builder, by scanning the content folder with the `dist.jar`. It is recommended having the latest [version](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/#download) installed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually it was a bug. When you configure a path to the Scene Builder in IntellijIDEA settings you have to wait after applying it until it's loaded completely and do not interact with it. Otherwise it goes to remain in the state of the first interaction with it.

Comment: @Alesto, Did you mean you actually managed to use Gluon's latest version embedded in IntelliJ IDEA's "Scene Builder" tab? No matter what I do, I am only able the see this new version as a stand-alone version.