# IntelliJ bug: it removes SceneBuilder functionality

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder, intellij-15

I noticed, that the very same FXML file if opened with standalone SceneBuilder and SceneBuilder from withing IntelliJ is displayed differently:

[image]

I.e. most properties are absent in IntelliJ version (at right in the picture).

How to fix?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437277/javafx-scene-builder-lacks-most-of-the-options/35443851#35443851)

Comment: Why am I entering path to SceneBuilder executable then? If I omit the path, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You need to let IntelliJ about the Gluon's SceneBuilder path so you can open fxml files from IntelliJ. Or you can just run SceneBuilder an open them from it.

Comment: The path I set in IntelliJ, displays different picture when I run it (the very same path) directly

Comment: As I mention in the referred question, you shouldn't use the IntelliJ built-in SceneBuilder, but the Gluon's latest version. They are really different.